# Can I disable Opera's new email notification in the system tray?

Tags: email, notifications, opera

I use Opera as my email client. When Opera finds some new mail it adds a tiny envelope to its system tray icon.

It disturbs me. How can I disable this notification?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I use latest stable (9.64) on Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a setting in the preferences:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> *or* <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Go to the **Advanced** tab, then **Notifications**.
3. Uncheck **Show notification for new messages**

If you use Opera as an RSS reader, notification of fresh new feeds will also not be shown.

#### Elsewhere...

You may also need to edit the shortcut used to launch Opera in the first place.

For **Linux**, find the launcher and edit the properties to append `-notrayicon`, like so:

> opera %u -notrayicon

**Windows**, locate the shortcut, right-click on Properties and append the target line with `/notrayicon` so that it will read similar to this:

> "C:\Program Files\Opera\opera.exe" /notrayicon

In addition, you may need to do the following:

- Right-click a blank area of the taskbar
- Select Properties
- Choose the Taskbar tab if not already selected
- Customize... of Notification Area
- Find the Opera icon and select "Always Hide" for its behaviour

When done with the above, close out Opera and then start it up again.

The Opera icon will now not show up in the system tray.

Comment: Actually this setting disables only annoying popup with extracted email headers. It doesn't disable changing system tray icon from ,,opera logo'' to ,,opera logo with a tiny envelope''.

Comment: Added edit on how to remove for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Enter opera:config into your address bar. Type "notif" into the filter box. Uncheck the notifications you do not want. Click on "Save".

Comment: For me, "noti" does the trick - adding a "y" at the end fails to match the notification preferences.

Comment: Oops. Corrected.